# Laravel - display field from database only if default value is changed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have profile page where logged in user can edit information about himself.

There are some fields with default values, for example in `$user->about_me` there is default value: `Tell us something about yourself`. And when logged in user clicks on that message he can change it.

When other user is viewing his profile I want that he can see `{{ $user->about_me }}` only if this field is changed from original default value. So if this field is not changed, other viewers should not see anything.

It would be very cool if you can help me with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For user who looks at other user profile you need to use condition:

```
@if ($user->about_me != 'Tell us something about yourself')
  About user: {{{ $user->about_me }}}
@endif
```

However in my opinion much better solution is to keep such fields empty in database and for user who looks at other user profile use:

```
@if ($user->about_me != '')
  About user: {{{ $user->about_me }}}
@endif
```

and for user who look at his own profile / wants to edit use:

```
@if ($user->about_me != '')
  About me: {{{ $user->about_me }}}
@else
  About me: Tell us something about yourself
@endif
```